# What is the difference between Mscratch and Mtvec Registers?

Tags: riscv

For Mscratch:. Typically, it is used to hold a pointer to a machine-mode hart-local context space and swapped with a user register upon entry to an M-mode trap handler.
For Mtvec: register that holds trap vector conﬁguration, consisting of a vector base address (BASE) and a vector mode (MODE).

I couldn't clear the difference between two. Can anyone clear it out?

Answer (score 1):

The `mtvec` register is directly used by the hardware: it is the address of the first instruction to be fetched when a machine-mode trap is handled.  Assuming traps are enabled, this can happen at any time so it's generally not safe for software to store arbitrary values in `mtvec`.  In fact, `mtvec` is usually written a small number of times during the initialization of the machine-mode software and then retains that value until reset.

In contrast, the value of `mscratch` is never used directly by the hardware: it simply serves as an `xlen`-bit long temporary scratch space that can be used by machine-mode software, is protected from other privilege modes, and can be accessed without destroying the contents of any X register (via a CSR swap instruction).

The canonical case is to set `mtvec` to an assembly sequence that first swaps `sp` into `mscratch`, which results in a clean trap handling stack that can then be used to the rest of the registers before entering a C trap handler.  This allows the machine-mode software handle traps without destroying the contents of the X registers, which is necessary for many common system features such as multiprogramming.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know MTVEC holds the vector for to where the program will jump when there is an interrupt.
mscratch is a pointer which may be used as an alternative to the stack pointer when inside an interrupt function.